# VBA Looping using Google Translator

Tags: vba, loops

I have the following script:

```
s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = transalte_using_vba(s)
```

Every time A column has value the translation will be pasted in the corresponding B column.  Example if A7 has value, the translation will be placed in B7.  I hope it's not confusing.

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: How can I create a loop example, every time A column has value the translation will be pasted in the corresponding B column. Example if A7 has value, the translation will be placed in B7.

Comment: You want *the entire code* that goes to Google Translate and sends the user input and pastes the translated result into your workbook? I sincerely doubt that this will happen.

Comment: It's working here:

s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = transalte_using_vba(s)

Comment: I just want to create a loop

Comment: Ah! Okay, misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106022/discussion-between-bot-sundi-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the sheet's [`UsedRange` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) with a `For Each` loop, like this:

```
Sub TranslateAll()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim inputCell As Range, outputCell As Range

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each inputCell In sheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:A").Cells
        Set outputCell = sheet.Range("B" & inputCell.Row)
        If inputCell.Text > "" Then
            outputCell.Value = transalte_using_vba(inputCell.Text)
        Else
            outputCell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  What if only blank cells in column B?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Column B only gets overwritten, the Sub does not care what values are in there.

Comment: I do have a set of data in column A but in column B, not all are translated and I want only blank fields that needs to be translated.

Comment: Look at the line with the `If` and think about it for a minute.

Comment: I'm thinking of: 

If Trim(inputCell.Text) > "" && Trim(outputCell.Text)  = ""

Comment: got it..it should be  If inputCell.text > "" And outputCell.text = "" Then

Comment: can I used this even if I'm offline?

Comment: That depends on how your translation function behaves when you're offline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106035/discussion-between-bot-sundi-and-tomalak).

Comment: I used this:

IE.Visible = False 
IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" & outputstring & "/" & text_to_convert